# play-1.2.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, playframework-1.x

I am trying to run the play-1.2.3 on Ubuntu. It gives me the following error:

```
@6bie96pcn
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /favicon.ico

Oops: RuntimeException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/forum/tmp/bytecode/DEV/DocViewerPlugin (No such file or directory)

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:525)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:599)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:186)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/forum/tmp/bytecode/DEV/DocViewerPlugin (No such file or directory)
    at play.classloading.BytecodeCache.cacheBytecode(BytecodeCache.java:103)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:159)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.reloadApplicationPlugins(PluginCollection.java:141)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:440)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/forum/tmp/bytecode/DEV/DocViewerPlugin (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at play.classloading.BytecodeCache.cacheBytecode(BytecodeCache.java:84)
    ... 8 more
14:42:40,419 ERROR ~
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: it seems the package is expecting some files to be located under /usr/lib/play-1.2.3/. What is this package anyway? where did you get it? how did you installed it?

Comment: I installed the package through play framework website. I have JDK6 installed on my machine. I included play into the path

Answer (score 0):

I would establish the following 2 points.

Does the file and directory */usr/lib/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/forum/tmp/bytecode/DEV/DocViewerPlugin* exist?

Does user play is running under have permissions to access /usr/lib/play-1.2.3/play-1.2.3/samples-and-tests/forum/tmp/bytecode/DEV/DocViewerPlugin?